# Function Return Error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

I'm trying to make a binary search of all prime numbers up to `num`, but the `search()` function won't `return` the booleans so that the `prime_maker()`function will `print` 'It's a prime!'.

```
def split_list(x):
       spliting = len(x)//2
       return x[:spliting], x[spliting:]
def search (A, a):
       B, C = split_list(A)
       if a <= A[-1] and a >= A[0]:
           if A[len(A)//2] > a:
              A = B
              if A[len(A)//2] != a:
                  search(A,a)
               else:
                   # print('It is a prime!')
                   return True
                   # This won't return 
           elif A[len(A)//2] < a:
               A = C
               if A[len(A)//2] != a:
                   search(A,a)
               else:
                   # print('It is a prime!')
                   return True
                   # This won't return 
       else:
           # print('It is not a prime.')
           return False
def prime_maker():
    a = int(input('Is it a prime?: '))
    num = 100
    prim = []
    for x in range(2, num + 1):
        isPrime = True
        for y in range(2, int(x**0.5)+1):
            if not (x % y):
                isPrime = False
                break
        if isPrime:
            prim.append(x)
    if a < 0 or a > num:
        print ('Insert a number between 0 og %d' % num)
        prime_maker()
    else:
        if search(prim,a):
            print('It\'s a prime!')
        else:
            print('It\'s not a prime')
prime_maker()
```

Why doesn't the `search()` function `return` the `booleans` so that the `prime_maker()`function prints the right `if-statment` in the last few lines?

Comment: For one, where you're recursing you're just calling `search(A,a)` instead of returning its result, like `return search(A,a)`.

Comment: Can you specify where the flaw is?

Comment: In the two `else:` clauses where you're just calling `search(A,a)` instead of doing `return search(A,a)`.

Comment: It's suppose to run `search()` again with new values for `A`